# Enforcing Uniqueness Across Database Tables

Tags: database, oracle, database-design, oracle11g, relational-database

I'm developing a multi-tenant database for an existing system that has the following requirements:

- A tenant has one-to-many entities.
- An entity may belong to only one tenant.
- An entity has one globally unique identifier.
- An entity has one-to-many unique aliases.
- An entity has other non-unique properties.
- An alias may only exist once for any given tenant.

To help illustrate, the following entities are all valid:

```
|-------------------------------------|
| Tenant   | Entity ID | Entity Alias |
|-------------------------------------|
| tenant-A | entity-1  | entity-a     |
| tenant-A | entity-1  | entity-b     |
| tenant-A | entity-1  | entity-c     |
| tenant-B | entity-2  | entity-a     |
|-------------------------------------|
```

However, given the following:

```
|-------------------------------------|
| Tenant   | Entity ID | Entity Alias |
|-------------------------------------|
| tenant-A | entity-1  | entity-a     |
|-------------------------------------|
```

The following entities are not valid:

```
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Tenant   | Entity ID | Entity Alias | Reason                                                |
|-------------------------------------|-------------------------------------------------------|
| tenant-B | entity-1  | entity-b     | "entity-1" cannot belong to multiple tenants          |
| tenant-A | entity-2  | entity-a     | "entity-a" is an alias already used within "tenant-A" |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

The key challenge with this is the "An alias may only exist once for any given tenant." requirement. Without this, the design would simply look like the following:

[image: Option 1]

However, this approach does not allow for a unique index to be placed on the TENANT + ALIAS. This may be another case of wanting a [unique constraint to span multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21090107/how-can-i-maintain-a-unique-identifier-amongst-multiple-database-tables), which is not technically possible.

Several other threads seemed to touch on this point, but didn't describe quite the same case:

- [How to enforce uniques across multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292298/how-to-enforce-uniques-across-multiple-tables)
- [How Can I Maintain a Unique Identifier Amongst Multiple Database Tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21090107/how-can-i-maintain-a-unique-identifier-amongst-multiple-database-tables)

There are a few other options presented below, each with some downside. I'm initially targeting Oracle 11g, but ideally there would be no proprietary DBMS constructs used in the design, if possible. Further, at this point, there is only one application which will be utilizing the database, so it is possible to enforce some of the requirements, but again, this would not be ideal.

### Option 1

[image: Option 1]

As mentioned above, this violates "An alias may only exist once for any given tenant."

### Option 2

[image: Option 2]

This approach works, although it feels a bit heavy, dragging the tenant along with the already-unique entity id.

### Option 3

[image: Option 3]

This approach may be feasible but does not enforce the requirement that "An entity may belong to only one tenant." The application code can prevent this occurrence if necessary, but ideally, I'd rather not even allow for this possibility in the database at all. For example, this approach allows the following invalid entities, where a single entity has aliases in other tenants:

```
|-------------------------------------|
| Tenant   | Entity ID | Entity Alias |
|-------------------------------------|
| tenant-A | entity-1  | entity-a     |
| tenant-B | entity-1  | entity-b     |
|-------------------------------------|
```

### Option 4

[image: Option 4]

This approach will allow for the seemingly appropriate design of "Option 1", but uses Oracle materialized views to effectively join the tables and allow uniqueness constraints to be applied between them. This approach seems to work, although I don't have any past experience with materialized views, so I may need to do some further testing to ensure that I'm not overlooking any other problems. The known downsides are that this is Oracle-specific and materialized views do have some inherent downsides such as requiring additional disk space and presumably having some effect on the performance of inserts/updates since the view would also need to be updated.

### Option 5

Option 5 would be to use either "Option 1" or "Option 3" along with some triggers to enforce the missing requirements. I'd prefer not to use triggers if possible as these can also be a bit heavy, may be DBMS-specific, and are unlikely to be the most efficient way to manage the requirements.

### Summary

On the surface, this doesn't seem like it should be a unique or difficult problem to solve, yet none of the options feels quite appropriate. At this point, I'm leaning toward *Option 2* or maybe *Option 3*, but I'm not convinced yet. Is there a straightforward option or perhaps a solution that I'm overlooking?

Comment: First, define your objects. What, exactly, is an "entity"?   What is a Tenant? what is an Entity-Alias?  If  "An alias may only exist once for any given tenant.",  then entity-alias is no more than an alternate key for tenants

Comment: Specifically in my use case, the "entity" is "User" and "alias" is "Username". I just used more generic terms to make it more applicable. A "tenant" really is just that - an identifier representing different buckets of users in a multi-tenant system.

Comment: a "tenant" is a "bucket" of users ???   ok.... but if so, then why can't you have more than one alias per tenant ? The restriction on aliases would be tied to users, not to tenants...

Comment: Yes, a tenant is just a logical unit identifier segregating different entities within the system... just a standard [multitenant system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitenancy), using a shared database with a tenant discriminator column.

Comment: Please define these terms in English, not in databaseese... Defining a tenant as a "logical unit identifier" does not explain much,  every key in the system is a "logical unit identifier".  FOR EXAMPLE, "a TENANT IS AN INDIVIDUAL OR LEGAL ENTITY ENGAGED IN A CONTRACT TO LEASE/RENT A PIECE OF REAL PROPERTY",  ETC. ETC.

Comment: A tenant is just an identifier defining a business. The tenant and its identifier are defined externally, and brought into the system only to group together entities (users) belonging to the tenant.

Comment: "The restriction on aliases would be tied to users, not to tenants." That's the trick; the restriction applies to both. To provide a more concrete example - A user may have multiple unique usernames, however, that username may not be used by more than one user within the same tenant. For example, google may have a user named "bob" and yahoo may have a user named "bob", but neither google nor yahoo can have more than one "bob". The system I am migrating allows a single user to have multiple usernames, which is why the relationship and uniqueness constraints aren't quite as straightforward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up moving forward with *Option 2*, such that the `TENANT_ID` was included in both the `ENTITY` and `ENTITY_ALIAS`. This seemed to be the safest approach, meeting all requirements of the data model, and having few drawbacks. Further, this approach provided the best foundation from which we can likely easily migrate to any of the other approaches in the future if appropriate.

[image]